# NetworkX Python Diferrent output with same input

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Why everytime that a script runs shows a different structure?
Like, the logic it´s the same but it shows diferent order, is there a way to keep the same seed or structure?
Examples of same data but different results:
[image: Example of the same data]

[image: Example of the same data]

Comment: Please create a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include it. Then we can help you more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the position of the nodes in a variable so that the network is represented always in the same way:
First create the graph:

```
G1 = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(20, 2)
```

Then run the layout function:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G1)
```

Then draw the graph like this:

```
nx.draw(G1, pos=pos)
```

The [nx.spring_layout and other layout functions](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) also allow for a `seed` value:

```
nx.spring_layout(G1, seed=31415)
```

---

Please note that the order of the nodes in you graph may change each time you create your graph. This may be what is affecting the layout of the graph.
Try to run each function separately.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? What are you trying exactly?

Comment: Added some more info to the answer